# Celery/django duplicate key violations

Tags: django, celery

I have a single celery worker with 5 threads. It's scraping websites and saving domains to DB via django's ORM.

Here is roughly how it looks like:

```
domain_all = list(Domain.objects.all())
needs_domain = set()

for x in dup_free_scrape:
    domain = x['domain']
    if any(domain.lower() == s.name.lower() for s in domain_all):
        x['domainn'] = [o for o in domain_all if domain.lower() == o.name.lower()][0]
    else:
        print('adding: {}'.format(domain))
        needs_domain.add(domain)

create_domains = [Domain(name=b.lower()) for b in needs_domain]
create_domains_ids = Domain.objects.bulk_create(create_domains)
```

Probably not the best way, but it checks domains in one dict(dup_free_scrape) against all domains already in database.

It can go over hundreds or even thousands before encountering the error, but sometimes it does:

> Task keywords.domains.model_work[285c3e74-8e47-4925-9ab6-a99540a24665]
>   raised unexpected: IntegrityError('duplicate key value violates unique
>   constraint "keywords_domain_name_key"\nDETAIL:  Key
>   (name)=(domain.com) already exists.\n',)
>   django.db.utils.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique
>   constraint "keywords_domain_name_key"

The only reason for this issue I can think of would be: One thread saved domain to DB while another was in the middle of code above?

I can't find any good solutions, but here is and idea(not sure if any good): Wrap whole thing in transaction and if databaise raises error simplty retry(query database for "Domain.objects.all()" again).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are creating these records in bulk and multiple threads are at it, it's indeed very likely that `IntegrityError`s are caused by different threads inserting the same data. Do you really need multiple threads working on this? If yes you could try:

```
create_domains = []
create_domain_ids = []

for x in dup_free_scrape:
    domain = x['domain']
    new_domain, created = Domain.objects.get_or_create(name = domain.lower()
    if created:
        create_domains.append(domain.lower())
        created_domain_ids.append(new_domain.pk)
```

Note that this is all the code. The select all query which you had right at the start is not needed. `Domain.objects.all()` is going to be very inefficient because you are reading the entire table there.

Also note that your list comprehension for `x['domain']` appeared to be completely redundant.

`create_domains` and `create_domain_ids` lists may not be needed unless you want to keep track of what was being created.

Please make sure that you have the proper index on domain name. From [get_or_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) docs:

> This method is atomic assuming correct usage, correct database
>   configuration, and correct behavior of the underlying database.
>   However, if uniqueness is not enforced at the database level for the
>   kwargs used in a get_or_create call (see unique or unique_together),
>   this method is prone to a race-condition which can result in multiple
>   rows with the same parameters being inserted simultaneously.

Comment: Makes a lot of sense, but won't get_or_create query database a lot? Because sometimes it's adding 100+ domains at time. Thanks

Comment: It will but 100 queries will probably be more efficent than looping through the entire table which might have hundreds of thousands.

Comment: besides in the original code you actually have a nested loop due to the any condition check.

Comment: You are right, I tested with 1mil domains dummy database and get_or_create is at least 200x faster then my old method. Cheers